# React Grid Layout not updating height

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I have one RGL component in my application. It is rendered correctly but when I add some content in Grid item then the content overflows the grid item. It is not pushing the Grid item to increase the height also I tried after updating `h` component in layout but updated layout isn't respected too.

PS: This works me - I'd to update the `key` prop every time the height was updated`. In short I'd to force re-render the RGL component. And the easy way for me was simply update the` keys`.

Comment: Did you find a way to get it to work or are you still looking? I ask because I too have the same issue and the repo seems to be stale with any updates.

Comment: https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/issues/1095#issuecomment-570782476 it works for me.